# How to design the DB that can remember the information of the current GUI instead of storing the info in the url?

Tags: java, php, mysql

Ok, here is a real challenge.

I am building a Ajax-based web app that has a very rich data in each page.

Ok, let see this scenarios.

User can retrieve variety of product within a period. For example, when user enters the url `mydomain.com?getProduct;startDate=2012-11-10;endDate=2014-12-11`, the system will retrive all product within that range & show all products on the page. Each product will has an ID and will be stored inside a checkbox as depicted in the following:

```
 
   Date       - Name - ID
[] 2012-11-10 - car  -10
[] 2012-11-11 - bike -11
.....
[] 2014-12-11 - bin  -110
```

Now the user will select some checkboxes Randomly & some other info will be displayed accordingly. And the user wishes that he can show a SnapShot of his current Working Gui to his bos.

SO, the current solution that I am doing is to store the productID in the url. For example, the user checked 2 productIDs `10` & `11` then the url should become `mydomain.com?getProduct;startDate=2012-11-10;endDate=2014-12-11;selectedIds=10_11`. The user then sends this url to his bos, the bos opens the url & saw the exact same Gui as the user had before like the following:

```
 
    Date       - Name - ID
[x] 2012-11-10 - car  -10
[x] 2012-11-11 - bike -11
.....
[]  2014-12-11 - bin  -110
```

The problem is the thr url could become very very long & Google don't want to crawl on a very long url. Also, very long url is pretty inconvenient when sent to email.

So, what is the best solution to this requirement? Should I have another table to store info instead of storing info on the url. But if that is the case then my DB will be very big cos user will produce lots of urls / day.

I am using MYSQL, but this is a general DB question so it doesn't matter which DB platform u r using.

Comment: create temp urls, save in db and remove expired ones on a cron. Or just except long urls - google wont be crawling these internal urls anyway

Comment: removed the expired url? what about many months later & the bos want to check again that old url?

Comment: Another solution is to save query parameters/query results in db. It's much better than just keeping url, because you can, for example use this data to get some stats or offer some propositions to users in the future.

Comment: but will be too many urls and could waste some resource. I am thinking if we can create a table with a special structure that can store variety of different combination of productsIDs cos may url could be the same so we don't need to store

Comment: So we need to figure out a Structure to manage all these.